# Rails joins value from association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join

I have two model Group and Item

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :group
end
```

my query

```
Group.joins(:items).select('items.created_at AS item_created_at, groups.*').where("items.created_at > ?", time)
```

I need load uniq groups with field 'item_created_at' like MAX(items.created_at)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like:
Group.joins(:items).select('max(items.created_at), groups.*').references(:items) ?

Not sure if that is what you want, but i think that would fetch all groups and their newest items' created_at.

Answer (score 0):

May following things work,

```
g = Group.joins(:items).select('MAX(items.created_at) AS item_created_at, groups.*').group('items.group_id').having("items.created_at > ?", time)
```

Now `g` gives groups with max created_at items in `item_created_at`,

```
puts g.map(&:item_created_at)
```